# how to make Pagination in laravel to return values in json format

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have client controller that sends request and server controller that processes the request and sends response.

How to paginate the response json data in laravel.

Server Controller

```
public function index() {

    $data = languages::where('is_active','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();   
    $response = Response::json($data,200);
    return $response;
}
```

Client Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $url = url('languagesService');
    $data = json_encode(array("username" => $this -> username,"password" => $this -> password));

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = CURL_EXEC($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    return View::make("languages.index")->with("data",$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is quite simple. Have you tried something like :

```
    public function index() {

    $data = languages::where('is_active','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate($perPage);   
    $response = Response::json($data,200);
    return $response;
}
```

**UPD:**
In case you want to paginate elsewhere of `index()` action, then you should create manually the paginator object via native Paginator class. You can find additional info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage). As quick example, you should do on your client controller:
`$paginator = Paginator::make($data, count($data), $perPage);`

And then use the `$paginator` object to achieve what you want.

Comment: No, i don't want the server to do the pagination. I want the pagination to be done in client side controller. Because the server side controller response is common to be accessed by other applications.

Comment: i tried this using $data = Paginator::make($paginator, count($paginator), $perPage), its working but i m getting all results in all pagination pages. Links working but all records are being displayed. instead of the perpage records

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the collection, it will convert to JSON itself.

```
public function index() {
    return languages::where('is_active','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate();   
}

// If you add `page` param into URL, Eloquent gets you content for specified page.
$url = url('languagesService', ['page'=>0]);
// $url = url('languagesService', ['page'=>20]);
```

I advice you send links for previous/next page together with total count of items so that API consumer can retrieve more elements if needed.

```
public function index() {
    $data [
        'data' => languages::where('is_active','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate()->toArray(),
        'total' => getNumberOfAllEntitiesThatFitFilter(),
        'nextPage' => getUrlForNextPage(),
        'previousPage' => getUrlForPreviousPage(),
    ];

    return Response::json($data);
}
```